# Difference between two tables with same primary key but different 2nd column

Tags: sql, select, insert

I have two versions of a database (v1 and v2) and I collect everything which is new in v2 and INSERT INTO it into a temp-database with this query

```
INSERT INTO [tmp].[dbo].[Mat] 
    SELECT * 
    FROM [v2].[dbo].[Mat] 
    WHERE myid NOT IN (SELECT myid FROM [v1].[dbo].[cMat_Mat])
```

The columns of table `Mat` are `myid` (primary key), `matnumber` and a few others.

The problem is, we have changed in some cases the `matnumber` but it doesn't see it as new because I compare only `myid`.

So here is my question. I need those rows which are in `[v1].[dbo].[cMat_Mat]` and `[v2].[dbo].[Mat]` and have the same `myid` BUT a different `matnumber`. How can I query that? ...with `SELECT` to see prove the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `join` the tables with the required conditions.

```
INSERT INTO [tmp].[dbo].[Mat] 
SELECT v2m.* 
FROM [v2].[dbo].[Mat] v2m
JOIN [v1].[dbo].[cMat_Mat] v1m on v1m.myid = v2m.myid and v1m.[cMat_Mat] <> v2m.[cMat_Mat]
```